# Volume bounded by ellipsoid wedge and plane

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, python

Given an ellipsoid $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} =1$ and a plane $z=k$ where $0<k<c$, how do I find the volume bounded by a 60° wedge of said ellipsoid and the plane? I'm not sure how to formulate the triple integral in spherical coordinates (or is it better to compute in cartesian?) and I'm planning to use Python to compute the volume.

Here's a sketch in the z-x and z-y axis: I would like to find the volume (yellow) bounded by the ellipsoid wedge (black) and the plane (dark red) 
[image: Sketch in ZX]
[image: Sketch in ZY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The volume integral can be expressed as,

$$ V= \int_{A(x,z)}2b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}}dxdz $$

The $xz$-integral is over the shaded area of the graph on the right, for which $y=0$.

Rescale the variables as $u=\frac xa$ and $v=\frac zc$. The ellipsoid equation for $y=0$ becomes $u^2+v^2=1$, the wedge lines $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}z$ becomes $u = \pm\frac a{\sqrt3c} v$ and the cut line $z=k$ becomes $v=\frac kc$. As a result, the volume integral becomes,

$$V = 2abc \int_{A(u,v)} \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}dudv$$

Now, reexpress the $uv$-integral in its polar coordinates,

$$V= 2abc\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\int_{\frac k{c\cos\theta}}^1 \sqrt{1-r^2}
\>rdr\>d\theta= \frac43abc\int_0^{\beta}
\left(1-\frac{k^2}{c^2}\sec^2\theta\right)^{\frac32}d\theta$$

where $ \beta= \tan^{-1}\frac a{\sqrt3c}$. In general, for arbitrary value of $\frac kc $, the last integral over $\theta$ would need to be performed numerically.

Comment: Nicely answered. However, the volume I'm interested in includes the semi-circle bounded by k and the currently shaded area you left out on your YZ diagram.

Comment: @bishopqpalzm - Thanks. I'm aware that it appears different. I did not shade it because that portion is the wedge surface. I should have used a different shade, which I do now.

Comment: Can you shed light into the last integration step? Online integration calculators seem to have issues with it. Also, the values I get from your solution is different from the values from my discrete 3D Riemann sum approach.

Comment: @bishopqpalzm - I tried the $\theta$ integral for a couple of cases. It seems to work fine. I used WolframAlpha integrator and did not have problem. If you let know the cases you had and maybe I could try on my end.